# user_login_finalize by default redirect to base_url/node page . How to alter redirection path

Tags: drupal-8

I am using user_login_finalize($user) for login user programmatically after save user data.
user_login_finalize by default redirect to base_url/node page  . How to alter redirection  path

Comment: Hello Zisu ! The Core function `user_login_finalize` from `core/modules/user/user.module` does not redirect the current Request. https://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/user/user.module#n550 Where do you use it ? In a custom Form maybe ? Or you may just want to alter the redirection of the Drupal core Login form ?

Comment: I want to implement Auto login and after Auto login , I want to redirect particular url

Comment: Can you add more of your current code ? What did you try already ? `hook` on the login Form maybe ? Or you may have a custom Controller to do your own "Autologin" ?